# Get permalink in attachment page for featured image

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wish to 301 redirect attachment pages in Wordpress to either the parent post or the homepage, in the below order:

1. Check if the attachment has a parent and redirect to that post url
2. Check if the image is used as a featured image and redirect to the post url
3. Redirect the attachment page to the site homepage

Points 1 and 3 are not a problem however I am finding it difficult to solve point 2.

This should be fairly trivial, like the rest of this code however it seems that if an image is used as a featured image in a page, then there is no post parent set (Correct me if I am wrong on that).

My code so far (at the top if image.php) is below:

```
if (!empty($post->post_parent)) { // checks the parent is set and not 0

    $url = get_permalink($post->post_parent);

} else if ( 'some code here' ) { // Check if the image is a featured image

    $url = get_permalink($some_variable_that_gets_the_url_of_the_page);

} else {

    $url = home_url();

}

wp_redirect($url, 301 );
exit();
```

Note: Yoast no longer does this and I don't want to use a plugin. In any case, I have yet to see a plugin that does what is described in point 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that accepts the id of the media, and check if anything in the database has a `_thumbnail_id` with the media's id.

```
function is_featured_image ($id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' AND meta_value = %s",
            $id
        )
    );
}
```

This will either return `false`, or the id of the post that's been found. If there are many, it will return the first post's id.

Then with the id, you can retrieve the url.

```
} else if (($id = is_featured_image($post->ID)) && $id !== false) {
    $url = get_permalink($id);
}
```

Comment: +1, but if I am not mistaken you could also do this with `WP_Query` class provided by WordPress. You can filter based on custom meta data: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: @RensTillmann Yes, but it would  make a long query for no reason. You only want the `post_id` in this case.

Comment: No, that's not true, WP_Query is just an higher level approach. You should always avoid using `$wpdb`. Only use $wpdb when  you need to perform queries not handled by core.